# Get location of the workbook calling the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlwings, vba

I am trying to execute the following Python script from Excel using

```
Sub MacrosTrigger()
    RunPython ("import MacrosTrigger")
End Sub
```

MacrosTrigger.py contains the following sample code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import xlwings as xw
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (18.0, 5.0)
wb = xw.Book.caller()
cwd = os.getcwd()
wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = cwd
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\HegdeP\\Desktop\\Python Data Analysis\\PST')
```

os.getcwd() returns the location of the Python interpreter. For automation purposes, I would like to be able to return the location of the workbook that is calling the script. i.e. location of the wb.

Comment: How about `wb.fullname`?

Comment: @Jeronimo That's the file itself. How do I get the address without the file name?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "address". Can you give an example?

Comment: `wb.fullname` will give me `C:\Users\HegdeP\Desktop\Python Data Analysis\OM646_Bio analysis\0172_1190790270172\xlwings trigger.xlsx`. I just want `C:\Users\HegdeP\Desktop\Python Data Analysis\OM646_Bio analysis\0172_1190790270172` as an input to `os.chdir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute path of an `xlwings.Book` can be obtained via the `fullname` attribute, so in your case `wb.fullname`.

In the comments you said you were only referring to the foldername. In this case, use

```
foldername = os.path.dirname(wb.fullname)
```

Check out the docs for [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) for lots of other useful functions to work with filenames.